# Conditional expectation versus correlation

Tags: conditional-probability, expected-value, conditional-expectation, conditional

Consider two random variables $X$ and $Z$. Suppose $E(X)=3$ and $E(X|Z=z)=0$ for some realisation $z$ of $Z$.

1. Does this imply that $X$ and $Z$ are correlated?
2. Does this imply that $X$ and $Z$ cannot be stochastically independent?

I think the answer to 2) is YES: if $Z\perp X$, then $E(X|Z)=E(X)=3$

I'm not sure about the answer to 1).

Comment: I have added some thoughts. Thanks

Comment: Do you really mean "some ... $z$" or did you intend to write *all ... $z$*?  There's little to be learned from a single value of the conditional expectation, after all, which is a strong hint to the answer to question (1).  The answer to (2) might depend on how you define conditional expectations.

Comment: I really meant some $Z$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A useful way to gain intuition in a problem like 1 is to try to think through the simplest cases. The simplest imaginable case is that $Z$ is binary (say, $Z \in \{0, 1\}$). Let's say $E[X | Z = 0] = 0$. Since $E[X] = 3$, the law of iterated expectations says
$$3 = E[X] = E[X | Z = 0] P(Z = 0) + E[X | Z = 1] P(Z = 1) = E[X | Z = 1] P(Z = 1)$$
For the above equation to hold, it must be the case that $P(Z = 1) > 0$ and $E[X | Z = 1] > 3 > E[X | Z = 0]$. In particular, this implies that $X$ and $Z$ must be positively correlated in the binary case (symmetrically, if we had instead assumed $E[X | Z = 1] = 0$, we would have that $X$ and $Z$ are negatively correlated. In either case, there is some non-zero correlation between $X$ and $Z$).

If we think more carefully about the above example, we might realize that while it suggests that while we found that when $Z$ is binary, knowing that $E[X | Z = z] \neq E[X]$ implied that $X$ and $Z$ are at least somewhat correlated, the way we showed it made pretty heavy use of the binary setting: our problem assumed (WLOG) that $E[X | Z = 0]$ is known for some value of $z$ while $E[X]$ was given, and the law of iterated expectations implied that once the distribution of $Z$ was pinned down, we had no remaining degrees of freedom to pick $E[X | Z = 1]$. This suggests that assuming $Z$ can take on three values gives us a considerable amount more freedom to pick things to construct a counterexample. Here is an example that does just that. $P(Z = -1) = P(Z = 0) = P(Z = 1) = 1/3$ and $E[X | Z = 0] = 0$. while $E[X | Z = 1] = E[X | Z = -1] = 9/2$, so $E[X] = 3$. In this case, we would have
$$Cov(X,Z) = E[X Z] - E[X]E[Z] = E[XZ] = 9/2 \cdot 1/3 + 0 \cdot 1/3 + (-9/2)\cdot 1/3 = 0$$
where the second equality is because $E[Z] = 0$. So even though $E[X | Z = 0]$ is known to be $0 \neq 3$, $X$ and $Z$ are uncorrelated.

Comment: Thanks. I'm unsure how to link your proof to my second question. I think that following holds: $E(X)=3$ and $E(X|Z=z)=0$ for some $z$ implies that $X,Z$ are dependent. I prove that by contradiction: suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are independent (and, hence, uncorrelated); then $E(X|Z)=E(X)=3$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: Oh, I should have added that your second statement is correct and your argument proving why it is correct is also correct

Comment: But they do not make sense together.

Comment: Why not? I am guessing that the main purpose of this exercise in the first place is to demonstrate that statistical independence is a _much_ stronger condition than uncorrelatedness (or put another way, being correlated implies statistical dependence, but statistical dependence does not imply correlation).

Comment: My counterexample gives a nice demonstration of why statistical dependence does not necessarily imply correlation. In my example, $X$ and $Z$ are statistically dependent in the sense that knowing the value of $Z$ tells us something about $X$. Specifically, knowing that $Z = 0$ tells us that $X$ is on average smaller than if we knew nothing at all.

Comment: On the other hand, because knowing $Z = 1$ or $Z = -1$ both tell us $X$ is larger on average than if we knew nothing, there is no "simple" rule for predicting $X$ with information about $Z$ of the form "when $Z$ is larger (smaller), $X$ tends to be larger", which is what we would need for $X$ and $Z$ to be correlated

Comment: THANKS! I summarise here all the comments. I read your proof as showing that: if $E(X)=3$ and $E(X|Z=z)=3$, then it DOES NOT necessarily imply that $X$ and $Z$ are correlated. We have also shown that if $E(X)=3$ and $E(X|Z=z)=3$, then it DOES necessarily imply that $X$ and $Z$ are dependent. These statements do not contradict because two dependent variables may have a zero correlation.

Comment: Since $P(Z=0)=0$ is a possibility, this does not imply dependence.